# How cann I trigger second intent after fulfilment of the first intent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am creating a food order taking chatbot in lex. After my first intent of taking veg starters is over, I want the bot to ask for order of non-veg starters automatically. I looked for online documentation, what I understand is that I have to use elicitintent but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

The exact return format depends on what version of Lex you're using. Lex V1 and Lex V2 have different return formats.

There's 2 `dialogAction` types that will bring you to a new intent: `elicitIntent` and `elicitSlot`.

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_DialogAction.html) say: `elicitIntent` - the next action is to determine the intent that the user wants to fulfill. I haven't used it in Lex V2 but in Lex V1, it doesn't always work the way I want to chain intents. In my experience, it listens to the user's next input and infers the intent from this. This doesn't really help if you want to chain a specific intent like in your case.

You can use `elicitSlot` to trigger your next intent.

In Lex V1, you'll need to include something like this in your return body:

```
dialogAction: {
        type: 'ElicitSlot',
        intentName: intentName, // Name of intent to be invoked
        slotToElicit: slotName // Name of the slot you want to invoke in the intent
    }
```

The return format is a little different in V2 but I believe the process is nearly the same.

If you have found a way to use `elicitIntent` for this purpose, please let me know! My understanding of it might've been incorrect so I'd appreciate the info.